# Serial communication between python and Arduino nano BLE sense 33 for running six DC motor

Tags: arduino-ide, communication, python

I am controlling six DC motors by varying their voltage. I have figured out the voltage required for each motor in python; now it's time to send this voltage through Arduino Nano BLE Sense 33 to run the six DC motors via serial communication.
Can anyone help me to figure out its solution?

```
Python Code:

from time import sleep
import serial
import struct
ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600) 

while True:
     ser.write(struct.pack('BBBBBB',200,210,220,230,240,180))  ## PWM
     ser.readline()
     sleep(.5)

Arduino Code:
const int ledPin[6] = {4, 7, 8, A5, 13, A0};
const int ledPin1[6] = {2, 6, 9, A4, 12, A1};
const int ledPin2[6] = {3, 5, 10, A3, 11, A2};

int x;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
    pinMode(ledPin[k], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin1[k], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin2[k], OUTPUT);
  }
  Serial.setTimeout(1);
}
void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    while (!Serial.available());
    x = Serial.readString().toInt();
    dir(ledPin[i], x, ledPin1[i], ledPin2[i]);
  }
}

float dir(int Pin, float x, int Lpin1, int Lpin2) {
  analogWrite(Pin, abs(x));
  if (x < 0) {
    digitalWrite(Lpin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Lpin2, LOW);
  }
  else if (x > 0) {
    digitalWrite(Lpin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Lpin2, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(Lpin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Lpin2, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried?  ... what failed? ... serial communication is not related to motor control ... the two functions are completely separate

Comment: I want to send voltage data from python to Arduino

Comment: By using serial communication, we can transfer data from python to Arduino. Here, in my program, that data is PWM. Once it comes in Arduino, I can run the DC motor.

Comment: Now, it will get clear. Please read the question once again.

Comment: Here, I have determined the voltage required for the DC motor(actuator). Now, I cannot operate the DC motor through python, so I am transferring data from python to Arduino IDE via serial communication. I know how to handle a single DC motor, but I have to run six DC motors here. In python, I have figured out the voltage for each motor, so it is in the form of an array. So, now I want to transfer this array from python to Arduino IDE, where I can run six DC motors.                 I hope you understand now.

Comment: The python code you have is sending six bytes of data in binary form as `b'\xc8\xd2\xdc\xe6\xf0\xb4'`, while you are reading it as a String (that is, a series of ASCII) in your Arduino. You need to read each byte like `byte x = Serial.read();` and deal with each data received.

Comment: Only one Dc motor is running, and the others are not running. I think it may be because they are not getting PWM values. Can you resolve it?

Comment: Thank you @hcheung.  I will try, and let you know.

Comment: Sorry @jsotola, I did not read your post carefully. I got now your question. I have already posted my code. It works for only one DC motor, and others are not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your Arduino `loop()` should look like:

```
void loop() 
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            while (!Serial.available());
            int x = Serial.read();
            dir(ledPin[i], x, ledPin1[i], ledPin2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it though.

Comment: It works. Thanks

Comment: @VishalNaik Please accept it as an Answer. Thanks! :)